# $x^2-x\lt0$ find the solution set of the inequality.

Tags: inequality

$x^2-x\lt0$

$x(x-1)\lt0$

I have stucked about preparing the table and which range should I get to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion:  first solve $x^2-x=0$

Comment: Looking at a graph of $y=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ might give you some ideas.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner thanks for the suggestion. I have found 2 roots for the equation. $x^2-x=0 \Rightarrow x(x-1)=0$ and solving for the roots that results 0 are $x=1, x=0$.

Comment: Good job.  Now you just have to check the sign of $x^2-x$ for $x<0, 0<x<1 $, and $x>1$

Comment: @kccu Yep, thanks. I did know this simplification. Sorry, I haven't mentioned it in the question. But I can't go any further after it.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner thanks. But I don't really get why we check their signs and how do you get these 3 inequality ($x\lt0, 0\lt x\lt1$ and $x\gt1$. Can you explain it, please. I'm sorry to make you busy :/

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN The expression $x(x-1)$ can only change sign (from positive to negative or negative to positive) if $x$ passes through a root, which you found to be $x=1$ and $x=0$. Therefore when $x<0$ the expression $x(x-1)$ will always have the same sign, when $0<x<1$ it will always have the same sign, and when $x>1$ it will always have the same sign. You just need to figure out on which of those regions it has a negative sign.

Comment: @kccu Oh, I get it right now. Thanks for the explanation. As I think, when $x\lt0$ sign of the expression $x(x-1)$ will postive, when $0\lt x\lt1$ sign of the expression $x(x-1)$ will negative and when $x\gt1$ sign of the expression $x(x-1)$ will positive. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN, that's correct. Now you have found the solution set!

Comment: Generally, if you can draw a picture that captures the essence of the problem them do so. In this case, if you sketch a plot of $x \mapsto x^2-x$ and where the graph is strictly below zero then you will see what the solution set it.

Comment: Thank you for enlighten me @J.W.Tanner and kccu. We just lastly checked out that which ranges satisfy our inequality. In this situations, it's only $0\lt x\lt1$ which is negative ( $x(x-1)<0$ ). I hope I'm right. Thank you so much again!

Comment: -1 The question itself is lacking context. You mention a table. Put it in the question. You mention you have factored $x^2-x$. Put it in the question. This way you won't be telling people "I already know that" when they are trying to help you.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, I agree with you. My bad. I'm sorry. I respect why you give downvote. I will take care of it better in next questions. I gave upvote to every comment and answers to make up my mistakes.

Comment: No, you should [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, observe that

\begin{align*}
x^{2} - x < 0 \Longleftrightarrow x(x-1) < 0
\end{align*}

Then consider $x < 0$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x > 1$. Obviously, when $x < 0$, then $x - 1 < -1 < 0 $. Thus $x(x-1) > 0$. Analogously, when $x > 1 > 0$, then $x - 1 > 0$ and, consequently, $x(x-1) > 0$. Finally, when $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we have that $x \geq 0$ and $x - 1 \leq 0$ and consequently $x(x-1) \leq 0$. Therefore the solution set for the inequality $x(x-1) < 0$ is the interval $(0,1)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me to solve this question!

Comment: No problem. You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$x(x-1)<0$$ and solve this inequality.

Comment: Ops, thanks for the hint. Forgive me I didn't mentioned about that I know this simplification. Sorry.

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN:  here's another hint:  product of positive and positive is positive, negative and negative is positive, negative and positive (or positive and negative) is negative

Answer (score 1):

1) Assume $x \le 0$:

We have

$x^2 < x$, which is impossible (why?).

2) Let $x >0$:

Then

$x^2 <x \iff x <1$.

Hence $x \in (0,1)$.